# Get hosted document within AfxOleControl42 control of other application

Tags: c#, windows, vb6, ole

As a feature my software should be able to import a file being currently shown in another specific german application.
This other application is a terrible super old piece of software written in VB6, that does not expose any API or anything.
Using Winspector i found out, that the files i am interested in are shown as an OLE Embed using AfxOleControl42.

Now my question is:

Is it possible to get the currently visible file of the AfxOleControl.
I know that using SendMessage and WM_GETTEXT its possible to get the content of a textbox when I know the handle.
Is there something similar for the OLE Control?

I would need code in C#, but i am thankful for any hint.

Thanks!